# React Native CameraRoll

Tags: javascript, react-native

My camera roll was working fine. Then I opened it back up and got this error:

```
[tid:com.facebook.React.RCTCameraRollManagerQueue][RCTModuleMethod.m:435] RCTCameraRollManager.getPhotos was called with 3 arguments, but expects 1
```

My javascript code is pretty simple:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  const fetchParams = {
    first: 100,
  };
  CameraRoll.getPhotos(fetchParams, this.storeImages, this.logImageError);
},

storeImages: function(data) {
  const assets = data.edges;
  const images = assets.map((asset) => asset.node.image);
  this.setState({
      images: images,
  });
},

logImageError: function(err) {
  console.log(err);
},
```

When I give it 1 argument, it gets angry and says I need a success and error callback. I have no idea what is going on here...Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What version of RN are you using ? I tested your example on RN 0.20.0 and it works fine.

Comment: I deleted some libraries and it seems to be working now.

Comment: Thanks for the help though!